# Client password confusion with PostgreSQL:

Tags: javascript, postgresql, windows-10

I'm attempting to access a PostgreSQL database in a JavaScript project on Windows 10. The program runs fine until I attempt to connect to the database, at which point I receive this message in the terminal.

`Error: SASL: SCRAM-SERVER-FIRST-MESSAGE: client password must be a string`

Here is the relevant pg code for access:

```
const Pool = pg.Pool;

const pool = new Pool({ 
    database: 'proth', 
    host: 'localhost', 
    port: '5432',
    max: 10, 
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000, 
});
```

I can't figure out how to set up a password for this sort of thing or what exactly I need to do.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the components you are using? Palin Javascript running on a browser should not be connecting to Database. you need a backend.

Comment: Also, name each software component involved (database server, database driver, ...) and their version.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.